# No working network after some errors on startup & a fsck

Tags: networking, server, dns

When I start the server, first I have to wait because of this:

```
A start job is running for Raise network interfaces
```

Right after showing Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS [...], before even logged in, following errors occur:

```
ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x180000a SErr 0x0 action 0x0
... some more ata erros
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 82075687
```

But I can still login in and do everything, except the network is not working. the cable is of course plugged in.

I tried some changes to /etc/resolv.conf which only 127.0.0.1 listed, but eg adding dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 did not help.
The /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

The enp2s0 is not started considering the output of ifconfig. If I try ifup enp2s0 I am stuck in a Network is down loop ...

Actually, I am not sure if the network is the real problem. Before this, I had to do a fsck of my /var partition (/dev/sda5) & then reboot. I must do this three times before the OS was running normally again.

Any tips, what to do to solve this problem?

Some more info: I ran this server for about 2 years without a problem. The /var/www contains some websites running using a LAMP stack.

Comment: Did you run fsck on the rest of your disk as well?

Comment: No, I did not, as there was a severe warning to so when the disk is still mounted. On the other main partition, the OS is running.

Comment: This is true - to run fsck currently on the root partition, you need to first boot from a live USB.  On the other hand, I was stuck in a boot loop until I did this once...

Comment: I did fsck from a live USB. It says both partitions are clean. Booting from the usb I also got internet, so it cannot be a hardware problem on the connectors or cable.